# MariaDB 10.11 triggers NaN Values

Tags: triggers, mariadb

I have a table with a float Column (NULL -> Yes, default value Null)
for exemple :

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `test` float DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

On Mysql 5 ->
`INSERT INTO test VALUES ('')`
was OK.

On MariaDB 10 ->
`INSERT INTO test VALUES ('')` 
gives me
#1366 - Incorrect double value: '' for column `nico`.`test`.`test` at row 1

i'd like to make a Trigger before insert to detect NaN value for test and replace it by NULL or 0.

I've tested

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER test_vide BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF NEW.test='' THEN
    SET NEW.test=NULL;
 END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

And

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER test_vide BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF NEW.test='' THEN
    SET NEW.test='0';
 END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

But it doesnt' work, i'm always having the error on insert in MariaDB 10.

Any advice ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to disable mariaDB Strict mode (syntax depending on your OS)

I've put

```
sql_mode = "NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf on my debian 12 server. it's ok to insert  using

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('')
```

but it doesn't answer the question how to use triggers in this case...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

While removing all sql_modes can allow the insert to happen, its only the [STRICT_TRANS_TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/#strict_trans_tables) SQL_MODE that needs to be removed to restore the previous behaviour:

```
MariaDB [test]> set statement SQL_MODE = REPLACE(@@SQL_MODE, 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', '') for INSERT INTO test VALUES ('');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]> show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                             |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '' for column `test`.`test`.`test` at row 1 |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from test;
+------+
| test |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```